# How to display selected file name in VisualC

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, mfc

I created a small MFC application which has a brose button and then a dialog box. on the button event, I am able to successfully open the select file option, but when I select the file, it doesn't get displayed in the Dialog box.

How can I do that?

Please help...

Comment: What do you mean the file is not displayed? You have to process the data of the file and have it displayed in a Label, ListView, TreeView (assuming is ASCII)

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you are using CFileOpenDialog? - after it returns, you need to get the selected file name from the CFileOpenDialog -

Answer (score 0):

by using
    GetModuleFileName(0, PathBuf, PathSize); You can get the pathname and by doing CString PathName = FileDlg.GetPathName(); you can get the path completely.